# how implement spring boot oauth2 sso with my own multiple web applications? these all application have own login page. is it possible or not?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2, oauth2client

We have multiple web applications, but our DB is conman for all. So, can we use "spring boot oauth2 sso" [requirement need like this flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaTz1.png) implementation with all applications with separate login pages? We want to handle common authentication for all web applications. Please check diagram that we need flow in my application?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

Comment: Siman thanks to given the answer, can it possible without jwt , because i just need   Implement spring security SSO without redirect to auth server (we can not show auth url to front end user, its working with backend process like server to server)

Comment: So please explain what you really want to do. What you're requirements are. If you already have a IdM

Comment: Hi @Simon , Sorry for delay,  we need service based approach to implement auth server with single sign on (SSO) . In our multiple applications that deployment is different with different login page in all applications . can it possible , we use auth-server services process in backend (not showing redirect url in browser)